# Google Play Private Channel "Restrict Distribution" option missing

Tags: android, publish, google-play, channel

I would like to publish our in-house apps using a Google Play Private Channel.

Here are the steps I've performed so far:

1. Registered for Google Apps for Business
2. Verified domain
3. Enabled Private Channel "Allow users to access Google Play Private Channel."
4. Registered and paid licence on Developer Console
5. Prepared an app for publishing

When I now go to the "PRICING AND DISTRIBUTION" section of my application,
there is no "Restrict Distribution" option as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322?hl=en). Instead my page looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S9vR.png).

I have tried publishing the app and then looking for the option. No luck.
It's been longer than the mentioned 48 hours it might take Google to propagate the changes.

Note: I used the same corporate email address everywhere, which is also in the verified domain.

Could you please tell me if I missed a step, or if you've had similar problems?

Comment: Did you get Solution for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you missed one step mentioned here, you need to turn on 'Allow users to update Google Play Private Channel' [Step 4, part1]
http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2494992